# gis calculate distance between point and polygon / border

Tags: python, gis, distance, shapely, geopandas

I want to calculate the distance between a point and the border of a country using python / `shapely`. It should work just fine point.distance(poly) e.g. demonstrated here [Find Coordinate of Closest Point on Polygon Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311616/find-coordinate-of-closest-point-on-polygon-shapely) but using `geopandas` I face the issue of:
`'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom'`

What is wrong in my handling of the data?
My border dataset is from http://www.gadm.org/

[image: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom']

Comment: As seen in the picture: 0 MultiPolygon dtype: object

Comment: Is `austriaBorders.geometry` really a shapely geometry? please, execute `print type(austriaBorders.geometry)`

Comment: I read the ESRI file via geopandas

Comment: so it the output of your command is geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/reference.html) documentation, a GeoSeries is a vector of geometries (in your case, `0 (POLYGON...` tells that you have just one object, but it is still a vector). There should be a way of getting the first geometry element. GeoSeries class implements the `__getitem__` method, so `austriaBorders.geometry[0]` should give you the geometry you need. So, try with `point.distance(austriaBorders.geometry[0])`.

If you only need the distance to a point, the `GeoSeries` has the `distance` method implemented, but it will return a vector with the distance to each geometry it contains (according to documentation).

Comment: indeed [0] is shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon