# Split lines in GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, shapely

I can find how to split 1 line using geopandas/shapely

```
def split_line_by_point(line, point, tolerance: float=1.0e-12):
    return split(snap(line, point, tolerance), point)
```

However I can't figure out how to apply this over an entire geometry column while maintaining other values.

Applying the above function to `df.geometry` loses a bunch of information

How do split a below linestring so that it 'explodes' maintaining 'type' and 'properties' cols?

```
{"Feature":'Hi',"ID":1,Linestring([1,1],[2,2],[3,3])},
{"Feature":'bye',"ID":2,Linestring([10,10],[20,20],[30,30])}
```

To

```
    {"Feature":'Hi',"ID":1,Linestring([1,1],[2,2])},
    {"Feature":'Hi',"ID":1,Linestring([2,2],[3,3])},
    {"Feature":'bye',"ID":2,Linestring([10,10],[20,20])}
    {"Feature":'bye',"ID":2,Linestring([20,20],[30,30])}
```

Lines need to be smaller where `length > x`

Comment: can you define these functions and post a complete code example, ideally a [mre]? what are split, snap, line, point?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I updated the post to reflect the type of function I need.

Comment: can you show what you've tried and what's not working? what do you mean that it loses a bunch of information? does `df['geometry'] = df.geometry.apply(split_line_by_point); df.explode()` not work? if not, why not? please check out the guide to [ask] - we really need your code and a clear description of what's not working to be able to help. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to solve similar problem in diferent topic.
Splitting whole line_gdf with point_gdf and preserve table:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78106911/13034952

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```py
import geopandas
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.ops import split, snap

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame([
    {"Feature":'Hi',"ID":1,"geometry": geometry.LineString(([1,1],[2,2],[3,3]))},
    {"Feature":'bye',"ID":2, "geometry": geometry.LineString(([10,10],[20,20],[30,30]))}
])

def split_line_by_point(line, point, tolerance: float=1.0e-12):
    return split(snap(line, point, tolerance), point)

result = (
    gdf
    .assign(geometry=gdf.apply(
        lambda x: split_line_by_point(
            x.geometry, 
            geometry.Point(x.geometry.coords[1])
        ), axis=1
    ))
    .explode()
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
  Feature  ID                                           geometry
0      Hi   1      LINESTRING (1.00000 1.00000, 2.00000 2.00000)
1      Hi   1      LINESTRING (2.00000 2.00000, 3.00000 3.00000)
2     bye   2  LINESTRING (10.00000 10.00000, 20.00000 20.00000)
3     bye   2  LINESTRING (20.00000 20.00000, 30.00000 30.00000)
```

Comment: this seems like a nice solution, but for a single point applied over a gdf of lines, if I'm reading correctly? Can you suggest how to tweak it so it could be applied to a gdf of points where each point gets snapped to the nearest linestring in a different gdf? (not all linestrings will get split).  For example, would it run inside of for i,d in gdf_points.iterrows() where point for the function is d.geometry?