# Get the coordinates of the closest point inside a MultiPoint in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I have a dataframe from which I created a Multipoint object:

```
points = MultiPoint(list(zip(dfxT['x'], dfxT['y'])))
```

The dfxT looks like this:

```
x | y | xT
2   3    1
2   15   5
2   28   6
```

And this is the `Multipoint` output:

[image]

And now I have a new tuple of coordinates and I want to check if they lie inside the `Multipoint` object and then get the `x` and `y` and retrieve the correspondant `xT` from the dataframe.

So basically I did this:

```
p = Point(10, 42)
a = points.intersection(p)
```

which returns nothing. I guess I am trying to see if the point is inside the multipoint and to get what I want I think I should get the closest point and `.loc` it on my dataframe.

So the question is: How do I get the `x` and `y` coordinates from the closest `Point` inside a `Multipoint` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coordinates of the closest points of two geometries in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415806/coordinates-of-the-closest-points-of-two-geometries-in-shapely)

Comment: Updated with the solution! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Georgy I was able to find a solution! Here goes:

```
p = Point(10, 42)
nps = nearest_points(points, p)[0]

xt_pts = np.array(nps).tolist()
```

Thank you!