# Why does matlab use the following interpolation function?

Tags: matlab, math, floating-point, linear-interpolation

If you try performing linear interpolation in matlab, it uses a "gridded" interpolant apparently.

Normally, I would expect the linear interpolation function to look something like this:

***METHOD A:***

[image: linear interpolation]

Where we wish to know the value of y(u) at u.

**However**, matlab seems to use the formulas below:

***METHOD B:***

1. Eq1

   [image]
2. Eq2

   [image]

So the result ends up actually being different if you use **method A** and compare the answer to **method B**.
The difference in the result I found to be around 2^-18 in double precision floating point arithmetic for certain inputs.

My Question:

Why does MATLAB choose to use Method B? It appears method A would involve less calculations. Also, is either formula "more" correct?

Performing method A should involve the following:

temp = (y(k+1)-y(k))/(x(k+1)-x(k))

y(u) = y1 + temp*(u-x(k))

Comment: one reason is that in method be you can iterate easily and use data from previous step. The formula is called temporal computing.

Comment: `2^{-18}` in difference is seriously nothing to worry about... that's essentially 0.  You can derive Method B from Method A by doing some very basic algebraic manipulations.  I also agree with NKN on temporal computing.

Comment: @rayryeng, I know it's small, but for my purposes, I want to know where all possible differences in results are occurring. Especially since I'm implementing an ASIC, small differences prevent me from "diffing" the results to perform functional verification.

Comment: @starbox - It's most likely due to the difference in order of operations.  For example, doing `(5.0 / 3.0)` and doing `5 * (1.0/3.0)` will actually give you small floating point errors between them both.  If you tried this, you would get a difference of almost `eps = 2.22e-16`.

Comment: @rayryeng, Thanks, I am aware of why the difference is occurring. I just don't like that it is :-)

Comment: No worries... Method A performs one mult, another mult then a division after to compute the right hand term.  Method B computes one mult, a division, then another mult after to compute the right hand term.  The difference in order of operations is probably why there is a small numerical difference between both methods.  There's honestly nothing you can do about it.

Comment: While the formulas are equivalent mathematically, they are not equivalent numerically. Eq2 used by MATLAB is widely preferred as it guarantees that both endpoints can be hit reliably in the presence of floating-point rounding error. With a small additional change, Eq2 also lends itself to a very efficient and accurate two-FMA computation: `fma (fma (-t_u, y_k, y_k), t_u, y_k1)`.

Comment: @njuffa - Nicely explained.  Consider making that an answer.

Comment: @njuffa, how do you know it is widely preferred?

Comment: Agree with njuffa, this is about floating point errors: if `y_k - y_k+1 << y_k`, small errors will be amplified, since you are subtracting big numbers. Method B seems also more 'symmetric' in `y_k` and `y_k+1`, which intuitively seems better (but it is still asymmetric in `x_k` and `x_k+1`). Somewhat related non-matlab questions [here (note first comment on accepted answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353525/floating-point-linear-interpolation) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907327/accurate-floating-point-linear-interpolation).

Comment: @rayryeng I cannot answer the question, I can merely *speculate* why the engineers at Mathworks decided to use that formula.

Comment: That comment didn't sound like speculation... it sounded like you knew what you were talking about....

Answer (score 0):

Both formulas are actually the same. You can check it yourself. Point being that they are not two different methods (A nad B). The only difference is the order or the computation. Check out my hand writing :)

[image]