# lerp for integers or in fixed point math

Tags: math, fixed-point

Is there an elegant way to do linear interpolation using integers? (To average ADC measurements in microcontroller, ADC measurements are 12bit, microcontroller works fine with 32bit integers). Coefficient f is in [0, 1] range.

```
float lerp(float a, float b, float f)
{
    return a + f * (b - a);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21379337/99691

Answer (score 5):

Well, since you have so many extra integer bits to spare, a solution using ints would be:

Use an integer for your parameter F, with F from 0 to 1024 instead of a float from 0 to 1. Then you can just do:

```
(A*(1024-F) + B * F) >> 10
```

without risk of overflow.

In fact, if you need more resolution in your parameter, you can pick the maximum value of F as any power of 2 up to `2**19` (if you are using unsigned ints; `2**18` otherwise).

This doesn't do a good job of rounding (it truncates instead) but it only uses integer operations, and avoids division by using the shift operator.  It still requires integer multiplication, which a number of MCUs don't have hardware for, but hopefully it won't be too bad.

Comment: Are A and B in this answer integers or floats?